# Publishing Node.js/Grunt website from my home machine

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have a site on node js and Grunt.

Son when in my terminal I run "grunt serve:dist" it publishes me the site on 127.0.0.1:9000

Now I want to publish this to the net, with no-ip.org

Here's what I did:

- Opened ports on my router:

  9000   9000   TCP/IP   192.0.1.11
- linking no-ip to my router
- disabling mac firewall

but either I go on a browser and do xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000 or mydomain.noip.me:9000 I don't see my website!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you call `listen(port, ip)` in your code that you specify `"0.0.0.0"` as the IP, meaning "all IP addresses". If your code is listening bound to the 127.0.0.1 loopback IP address, it won't accept remote connections by definition.